# Rapid and easy question on ideals and ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be the number ring related to a field $K$ of finite degree over $\mathbb Q$, i.e. $\mathbb Q\le K\le\mathbb C$ and $[K:\mathbb Q]=n$. Hence $R=\mathbb A\cap K$, where $\mathbb A$ is the ring of the algebraic integers in $\mathbb C$.

Suppose that $\forall \;I\unlhd R\;\;\exists\; a\in R$ s.t. $aI=R$.

Now in my book I read that from this follows that every ideal is principal. But i think found a (really) stronger fact: if $aI=R$, being $R=(1)$, then there exists $b\in I$ s.t. $ab=1$. But $ab\in I$, hence $I$ must be $R$.

Am I right?

Thank you all

Comment: If $R$ is a ring, $a\in R$ and $I$ is an ideal in $R$, then $aI\subseteq I$ just by the definition of ideal. Hence the assumption reads: $I=R$ for all ideals $I$ in $R$ ($I\unlhd R$ just means that $I$ is an ideal in $R$, right?). That would mean that $R$ is the zero ring.